# search dictionary in python for the matching value

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate % cpu utilization based on vmware quick stats. Problem is that quick stats does not provide % cpu utilization for guest, so I have to find a way to calculate it. I have the host cpu speed value pair store in a dictionary as follows:

> {'host-594': 2194, 'host-10249': 2194, 'host-6484': 2194, 'host-6486': 1861, 'host-6480': 2194, 'host-6482': 2194, 'host-699': 2194, 'host-6364': 1861, 'host-500': 2194, 'host-17424': 2194, 'host-502': 2194, 'host-17426': 2194, 'host-17420': 2194, 'host-17422': 2194, 'host-17428': 2194, 'host-1805': 2665, 'host-4360': 1862, 'host-858': 2194, 'host-1067': 2194, 'host-1065': 2194, 'host-4162': 1861, 'host-1063': 2194, 'host-1061': 2194, 'host-17396': 2194, 'host-3394': 2132, 'host-1069': 2194, 'host-5565': 2132}

Then,

I can get Used_CpuMhz,Num_vCpu, and host_id (which guest belongs to) as follows:

```
properties = ["name",
              "summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage",
              "summary.runtime.host",
              "config.hardware.numCPU"]
results = s._retrieve_properties_traversal(property_names=properties, obj_type=MORTypes.VirtualMachine)

for item in results:
        for r in item.PropSet:
               if r.Name == "name" :
                name = r.Val

        Used_CpuMhz = 0
        Num_vCpu = 0
        host_id = none


        for p in item.PropSet:

            if p.Name=="summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage":
                    Used_CpuMhz=p.Val  

            if p.Name=="config.hardware.numCPU":
                    Num_vCpu=p.Val  

            if p.Name=="summary.runtime.host":
                    host_id=p.Val
            #here I have to read myDict() where I need get the value pair
            #for host_id in myDict. I need to scan myDict and if I see host_id
            #in there, I need to assign the value to speed variable in here
                   %CPU= Used_CpuMhz/(Num_vCpu*speed)
```

Given this value: `{host-594': 2194}`, if the host_id in if statement is "host-594", speed should be 2194. So for each guest I need to scan myDict and find the matching host's cpu speed. Can somebody provide some insight how would go about doing this?

I have modified the code as below:

```
if p.Name=="summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage":
                    Used_CpuMhz=p.Val  

if p.Name=="config.hardware.numCPU":
                    Num_vCpu=p.Val  
if p.Name=="summary.runtime.host":
                    host_id=p.Val
                    if host_id in myDict:
                        cpu_speed = myDict[host_id]

if Used_CpuMhz >0 and  Num_vCpu >0:
                    Percent_Cpu_Used=(float(Used_CpuMhz)/(float(Num_vCpu)*float(cpu_speed)))*100
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "host.py", line 138, in <module>
    Percent_Cpu_Used=(float(Used_CpuMhz)/(float(Num_vCpu)*float(cpu_speed)))*100
ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

Comment: RTFM [mapping types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict) on `dict` operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if host_id in myDict:
    speed = myDict[host_id]
```

An equivalent way to do it:

```
if host_id in myDict.keys():
    speed = myDict[host_id]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have to initialize host_id before loop, I tried host_id = none did not work, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What behavior do you want when the hostid isn't in the dict?

Comment: @user1471980 try this `host_id = None` or `host_id = ''`

Comment: @killermonkey50, I've update the post with your answer. I now get dividing by zero error. Do I need to initialize host_id before the loop? I tried host_id=none, did not like it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify a default value to use if the host isn't found in your dictionary:

```
speed = myDict.get(host_id, 12345) # Default of 12345
```

Of course, if you do expect all of the hosts to be in the dictionary, then just look it up:

```
speed = myDict[host_id]
```